# How to find out where my error is coming from?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have an annoying error that's been popping up, and I don't know where it is coming from. The error is:

```
Error   31  Unable to copy file "app.config" to "bin\Debug\Framework.Tests.dll.config". Could not find file 'app.config'.   Framework.Tests
```

The problem is, I don't have a bin\Debug folder anywhere, and it does not say from where it is trying to copy app.config. Double clicking on the error doesn't bring me to any code where it is trying to copy, so that doesn't help me either. So I don't know where I should make the app.config.

How can I find this out?

Comment: Try to clean solution and rebuild to see what happens. Also check your build configuration.

Comment: Put it in your Framework.Tests project.

Comment: Do you have an app.config file in the project that is producing the error?  It may be the case the the project references a file called app.config, but it doesn't exist on the disk.

Comment: In my case, I believe the file reference was added spuriously by a Nuget package installation, as I did not add it myself and the file never actually existed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have added a reference to a file called `app.config` or Visual Studio did this for you. The file does not exist on the disk, presumably because after adding the reference you later deleted the file.

Search for the missing file in your Solution Explorer, and either delete the reference or create the file.

It is most likely in the root folder of one of your projects, and should have a yellow triangle warning icon showing that the file is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In an MSTest project the app.config is the one that you would like to provide any calls to the `ConfigurationManager` class.

It resides in the root of your test project.

The bin\debug folders will be created once the project compiles for the first time. Show all files in the solution explorer should help as they are not (and should not) be included in the project.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You probably do have a bin\Debug folder beneath your project folder, being the build target folder created by Visual Studio when you build your project for the Debug configuration.

My guess is that something (a test framework perhaps) still has the DLL file loaded, so Visual Studio can't delete and replace the existing Framework.Tests.dll.config file with the contents of your app.config. [Note: the project build action for app.config files is to copy it to the target folder renamed to match the executable with an extension of .config appended.]