# Trying to Publish C# Project but getting: Could not copy "App.config" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to publish a C# project on Visual Studio 2019 but I am getting the following error:

[image]

The properties for App.config is set to:
Build Action: None
Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy.

I've tried changing Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always and Copy if newer but still getting the error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It can't find the path. Read the whole error.

Comment: I double checked the file path and all the directories and files are there.

Comment: @minTwin, as usual, I suggest that you can try to delete the bin and obj folders and rebuild the project. Then, you can have a try to publish again to check if it works well.

Comment: I've tried deleting both the bin and obj folders and rebuilding the project. Both folders reappear after clicking to rebuild, yet the same error persists.

Comment: @minTwin, what did you do about the project before you get the error? By the way, I find the problem [How to find out where my error is coming from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524878/how-to-find-out-where-my-error-is-coming-from) may be similar to your question and you can have a look. If this not solve your problem, I suggest that you can upload a project here to let us check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by deleting the App.config file. After deleting that  file the publishing function works.

Comment: I'm glad its working now.  Unfortunately, this is an all-too-common workaround, instead of understanding the root of the problem.  Next time, you can try running both procmon to see the filesystem activity and the file IO issues like access denied, and also procexp and search for your App.config.  With procexp, you can see if another process has a handle on that file, which is preventing its deletion.  Then you can either stop that app (ie. your app that you're developing that may be still running) or force close the handle from procexp
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/